# GLEW libraries seems to have issues when linking

Tags: c++, glew

I'm getting really frustrated now with trying to link this glew Library

Here's the build log:

```
g++ -o test.exe "src\\test.o" -lglew32 -lglfw -lglu32 -lopengl32 
src\test.o: In function `main':
C:\dev\test\Debug/../src/test.cpp:31: undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
C:\dev\test\Debug/../src/test.cpp:41: undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenVertexArrays'
C:\dev\test\Debug/../src/test.cpp:42: undefined reference to `_imp____glewBindVertexArray'
```

I've tried moving around which libraries go first in the build command.

This seems to be an issue that others on the internet are having but i cant seem to find any of them that have fixed it

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of GLEW installed? (64bit as opposed to 32bit)

Comment: are you using the static version of the library? ( -lglew32s )

Comment: I've tried that and it still didn't work. Should i use both?

Comment: No, i dont think so. Ive had a very similar problem before.. Could i get some information about your system (OS, architecture)?

Comment: 64 bit Windows 7 my GPU is AMD HD6850 if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I know it's a bit wierd be answering my own question but here was the issue:

Apparently the errors were occuring in two areas

- For a starter, i didn't need glu32 only opengl32 as i beleive glew handled this itself
- Secondly, for some wierd reason i had to call

  ```
  #define GLEW_STATIC
  ```

  manually before I imported